# Why do PHP's built in functions use constants instead of just strings as parameters?

Tags: php

I noticed that PHP's internal functions never use strings for pre-defined or limited values, only constants.

[For example](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

> **pad_type**:
>
> Optional argument pad_type can be STR_PAD_RIGHT, STR_PAD_LEFT, or STR_PAD_BOTH. If pad_type is not specified it is assumed to be STR_PAD_RIGHT.

What's the reason for not using a string as parameter here?

`str_pad($test, 10, 0, 'left')` seems a lot simpler than `str_pad( $test, 10, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)`

(This is more of a meta question. I hope it's OK to ask here.)

Comment: there is a very big advantage when you are using an IDE with intellisense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to make mistakes when typing a string. Using an undefined constant will throw a warning. It's not just a PHP thing. Regular API functions (i.e. of an OS) usually use numeric constants as well for parameters like this.

Comment: Also add: for maintainability of the function. Say the guts of a function changes, so will most likely the parameter value(s) & types, too. Defining with a constant instead of an arbitrary string makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

They use `int` .. and it more efficient that way because of  Case Sensitivity , Spelling Mistakes , Parsing strings ,  Better for IDE , Error  etc.

If you don't like constant  you can just use int value

```
  str_pad($test, 10, 0, 0) == str_pad( $test, 10, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the type of `$pad_type` in the parameters is actually `int`. Passing ints is a lot faster than passing (then comparing) strings. So instead of passing a number into the function to tell it what to do, you pass the corresponding constant, making your code clearer. And if the PHP developers ever want to change it to pass strings instead of ints, they can do it without breaking any of your code, as long as you used the constants.